# How to automatically add mail recipients in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am working on to send an email on build failure to the users who had committed the code in Jenkins. I am using pipeline script. But i am struck now as i am manually adding the username. How to automatically add recipient mail in Jenkins.

Here is the code i have written.

```
emailtext attachLog: true,body: '', 
compressLog: true,
recipientProviders: [[$class: 'DevelopersRecipientProvider']],
subject:'Test results'
emailtext body : 'Commit failure', subject: 'Test-failure', to: 'abc@xyz.com'
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct structure for  this is:

```
emailext (
  subject: yoursubject,
  body: yourbody,
  recipientProviders: [[$class: 'DevelopersRecipientProvider']]
)
```

Your code can be similar to:

```
emailext (
  emailtext attachLog: true,
  compressLog: true,
  subject: 'Test results failure',
  body: 'Build failure',
  recipientProviders: [[$class: 'DevelopersRecipientProvider']]
)
```

For more info:
[Sending notifications pipeline](https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/sending-notifications-pipeline)

Comment: Hi trisquel, I tried the code which you have suggested but i am getting the following error- "Not sending mail to unregistered user abc@xyz.com because your SCM claimed this was associated with a user ID ‘abc' which your security realm does not recognize; you may need changes in your SCM plugin
An attempt to send an e-mail to empty list of recipients, ignored."